# How to get SEO working with my other bought domains that redirect to my main site?

Tags: url, redirect, dns

so lets say hypothetically that my domain is Iamadog.com. And this made up site is about dog treats.

I then build the site and do SEO on all articles etc.

What if I then go and buy dogtreats.com , and redirect it to Iamadog.com when someone types in the url.

My question is How can I make it so when someone goes on Google and types in dog treats , my site will show up ?

because in this hypothetical situation, from my testing  , The only way I can get someone to find my site through the 2nd domain I bought dogtreats.com is if that person Actually physically types the dogtreats.com domain in the url box, like they knew that was the website they were searching for. I want to make it so if they google dog treats that my main domain would show up " Iamadog.com" . Is this possible or is buying domains and redirecting them to your main domain only good if someone actually types it into the url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is some point you should aware of it:
1) Did Google know about your site? how? you should go to "Google web master" tools  and create account for your web site , and don't forget there is something very Important "The SITE MAP" so Google robot can easily navigate your website.

2)If you want your site to be on the top write special Unique content, redirecting or adding link to your site in different website is good but do it smartly so Google robot don't see you as a spammer.
Last thing your site "dogtreats.com" should have a good rank so you can see a real value of your links on it.

I wish i help you :)